# Case Sensitive URL Triggering CORS Error

Tags: javascript, python, json, url, cors

I am trying to access the [JSON metadata](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON) corresponding to Python packages in the form `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/<package_name>/json` using JavaScript.

My code looks something like this:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var url = 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/' + name + '/json';

$.getJSON(url, function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

The problem is that the url for the json is case sensitive, so for example, pypi.python.org/pypi/flask/json gets redirected to pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask/json since the package 'Flask' needs to have a capital F.

Thus, if `name` is flask, I get the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask/json. Redirect from 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask/json' to 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask/json' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Any idea on how to properly access the json even if the package name has the wrong capitalization?

Comment: Seems like a problem with pypi not setting headers correctly when redirecting. JSONP doesn't work either, as `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask/json?callback=f` works as expected (`f({...})`), but `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask/json?callback=f` redirects to capital F, and does not respond with the callback (It sends `{...}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the request through an open CORS proxy it should work; try changing your code to:

```
var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://pypi.python.org/pypi/' 
  + name + '/json';
```

That sends the request through https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, an open CORS proxy which adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to it and then passes that back to your requesting frontend code as the response.

That redirect response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees, so the browser will actually follow the redirect instead of stopping.

All the said, it seems like the pypi.python.org site should really be including the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in their 3xx redirect responses, so you might consider filing a bug at https://sourceforge.net/p/pypi/support-requests/ requesting that they do.